# Allow duplicated names in binded tables

Tags: r, kableextra

UPDATE for why I changed my votes.

This code has the table displayed but R doesn't knit pdf.

```
all_jt %>%
kbl(longtable = T, booktabs = T, 
      caption = "table") %>% 
  remove_column(7) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 2, "Year 1" = 4, "Year 2" = 4)) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header")) 

Quitting from lines 13-37 (test_table.Rmd) 
Error in remove_column(., 7) : 
  Removing columns was not implemented for latex kables yet
```

switching to `select(-7)` as in here [Remove_Column from a kable table which will be output as latex/pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67400096/remove-column-from-a-kable-table-which-will-be-output-as-latex-pdf) doesn't work because R doesn't like duplicated column names.

I have two ANOVA tables, `jt_1` and `jt_2` below, that I want to merge and keep 1 column for the model term only. As I remove the duplicated column, R added `.1` to the tail of columns' 7, 8, 9 and 10 names.

```
library(emmeans)
library(stringr)

warp.lm <- lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)

jt_1 <- print(joint_tests(warp.lm), export = T) %>% as.data.frame() 


jt_2 <- jt_1

all_jt <- cbind(jt_1, jt_2) %>% 
  setNames(gsub("summary.", "", colnames(.))) 

all_jt[,-6]%>% #to remove the duplicated column for model term
 data.frame(check.names = F) %>% 
kbl(longtable = T, booktabs = T, 
    caption = "table") %>% 
  add_header_above(c(" " = 2, "Year 1" = 4, "Year 2" = 4)) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))
```

Here is a brief idea of what I need.

[image]
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Not central to the main question, but it seems to me that piping `print(... export = TRUE)` to `as.data.frame` sort of defeats the purpose, since the point of that export argument was to make it *not* a data.frame.

Comment: I can only `cbind` the two `join_tests()` outputs after converting them to dataframes. The `export` command was to keep `p-values` formats as-is from the `join_tests()`

Comment: Yes, but I think you lose the alignment info. Everything in your output is left-aligned, and that could look pretty bad for the numerical columns. I suppose there's a way to fix that later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R does not like duplicate column names in `data.frame`s. If you step through your last code block line by line you will notice that `all_jt[, -6]` makes column names unique by adding the ".1" suffix.

The/a solution is to provide column names to `kbl` directly, e.g.

```r
all_jt[,-6] %>%
    kbl(longtable = T, booktabs = T, 
        col.names = gsub("\\.\\d", "", names(.)),
        caption = "table") %>% 
    add_header_above(c(" " = 2, "Year 1" = 4, "Year 2" = 4)) %>% 
    kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))
```

This produces

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where the problem came from.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `remove_column` function from `kableExtra` to remove a column instead of `all_jt[,-6]` which makes the column name unique.

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

all_jt %>%
kbl(longtable = T, booktabs = T, 
      caption = "table") %>% 
  remove_column(7) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 2, "Year 1" = 4, "Year 2" = 4)) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the neat solution. How did you remove all the dots after `model.term`? I can post another question if that's preferred.

Comment: Actually I did not got any dots in `model term` even after using your solution.